# how to display categories without topics

Tags: wordpress

How can I show categories with no posts on my wordpress site?
When I enter the urls of the category, it gives a page not found error. I want the blank page to appear even if there is no post linked to the category, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by editing your theme's template files. Look for the template file that contains the code for displaying your site's categories. In that file, find the code that checks to see if there are any posts in the category. If there are no posts, then that code should display a blank page.

Comment: I'm using generatepress. I searched but I didn't come across a code that returns this kind of query. I wonder if it can be done from the wordpress settings, or do you know where the relevant code is in generatepress?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `category.php` file in your theme root folder.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <?php if( have_posts() ): ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        
        Category info

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php else: ?>
        There is No categories to show
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: I got the error "There is No categories to show". Even the "category info" in the code did not appear. This text only appeared in the category with the post in it. Do you have an alternative solution? edit: I reviewed the code again, yes it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: But I still need to find another way. Since the theme is generatepress, I can't edit the category.php page again and structural problems may arise.